# Convert RTF document to PDF document in C# for Azure app service

Tags: c#, azure

I've been searching out for solutions to convert **RTF document** to **PDF Document** in C# and this should work fine in **Azure app service.**

we know that azure app service we cannot have the MS office/Third party software installed.So without MS office/thirty party  software can we convert RTF doc to PDF doc ?

I am running in the gray area with out any solution for this.
Any suggestions / or the approach to solve this in azure app service are welcome !!

Thanks
Kumar

Comment: This problem should be the need to purchase other third-party products for conversion, you search for `rtfconverter`.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a specific limitation against it, you should be able to use .NET DLLs from a Document Converter SDK in an Azure App Service.

One approach that you could consider that I am familiar with (as I work for the vendor of the toolkit) is the [LEADTOOLS Document Conversion SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/tutorials/documents/windows/dotnet/winforms/convert-files-with-document-converter.html).